# How to archieve induction isolation from adjacent inductors on a plane, but no isolation from inductors outside the plane

Tags: inductance, isolation, wireless-charging

I am thinking of designing a large wireless charging pad. The idea is to have many inductors in a grid setup, where when a phone is placed on the pad it starts charging from the inductors closest to it. There are weight sensors, so only the inductors directly under the phone will be powered with weight sensors, but how do I prevent adjacent inductors on the plane of the pad from being induced by the inductors that are on. The idea is to charge the phone, not to dispose power to adjacent inductors on the pad.

Comment: yes and how to minimize leakage radiation to eyes.  Maybe this is why Apple dropped this project.  Although coplanar coil mutual inductance will be low.

Comment: Wait what,does putting many inductors on a plane causes leakage radiation? Is that why big wireless charging pads don't exist?   @SunnyskyguyEE75

Comment: How do you prevent leakage radiation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, really.

But if you drive the inductors correctly, you can prevent any *power* from getting coupled.

Basically, make sure that your drivers are designed so that unpowered inductors see an open circuit.  To a large extent, that will make them look "invisible".